# GRUB starts but init cant read any media

Tags: system-installation, windows-10

So preconditions:
I'm looking at a new machine, win10 is installed.
I have easily downloaded the 20.04 iso.

I partition a section of the ssd at 10GB (sda5/D:) planning to copy the ubuntu installation media to that space.(disk manegment.)

Now it starts to get fun.

I google iso writer for windows. (probably a noob mistake).
The top google results are mostly spam and ads. I find some top 10/ top 5 that agree on

- Free ISO Burner

A no go, the iso was too large. Now I notice, there's also a lot of ads in the start menu. Fun!

I download and install and randomly execute 6 more viruses promising iso capabilities.

I finally download a virus that can actually extract an iso. (This is the end of your free trial, you can only do this in the pro version).

I manage to write the ubuntu 20.04 iso to a partition d: in windows. Formatted as FAT (and FAT32). A file copy.

I did the same procedure with a USB drive - same result.

GRUB starts
but init cant read any media.

in init I can see and ls (hd1,gpt5)/casper

I tried to edit the grub boot line to no avail.

Tried every variant of the secure boot options in the bios. On, Off, Clear keys. The Windows EFI partition is still there.

Comment: You've not been very specific on what 20.04 you're asking about. The recommended minimum size for a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop system is 25GB, but you mention 10GB only; but are you only using it instead of thumb-drive?  Why aren't you following official advice?  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview  (*20.04 desktop? server? 20.04? 20.04.1? 20.04.2? 20.04.3 etc.. being specific helps us to help you*)

Comment: Why not assume the standard desktop. 

>>I partition a section of the ssd at 10GB (sda5/D:) planning to copy the ubuntu installation media to that space.

Why not a thumb drive? 
Because the ssd is about 60 times faster.

The thumb drive failed too with exactly the same messages. 

I did follow the official recommendations, my only deviation was not using the rufus software.

Comment: @guiverc "I did the same procedure with a USB drive" - same result as is mentioned in the original question. I have reread my original question several times, and I can't for the life of me figure how to read this as I'm intending to install Ubuntu on my install media partition.  And I also expect that up until initramfs server vs. desktop is a non-issue. As would 20.04.x.

Comment: @ChanganAuto No, my intention was of course to let the installer do that work, as would be par for the course. I had no intention of keeping windows, I expected the snark to convey that.  My apologies.

Comment: You've not been specific on ISO thus we cannot know which installer you're talking about; however `ubiquity` will not let you install to the same partition it was read from; and will not let you full-disk install to the drive it was initially read from; but you may not be using `ubiquity` (you weren't specific) nor the version as you've not been specific as to release & ISO. I have less experience with `subiquity` & other installers you also have available for 20.04, but you've not been specific as to which you're referring

Comment: The first app I install with Windows or Ubuntu is **7Zip**. https://www.7-zip.org/. It is not a virus. It will open almost any archive file. Have a look at the following link I think it is what you are looking for: https://askubuntu.com/a/1364128/43926 It concerns booting an ISO extracted to a small partition on your drive without using GRUB, Syslinux, CD or USB. It boots directly using UEFI capabilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: @ChanganAuto If you extract the Ubuntu ISO to a FAT32 partition on a Windows disk UEFI will boot it, see my comment above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bad installation media(For the usb drive) gave these rather unhelpful messages.

This was compounded by the fact that RST, Intel Rapid storage, was activated on the disk. Which apparently makes it inaccessible to the Ubuntu installer (don't quote me on that). This is my first contact with Intel RST.

I strongly suspect that IRS made the install(iso extracted) partition behave similar to the faulty USB drive.

> RST & Ubuntu installation
>
> If you intend to install Ubuntu on a computer that supports RST functionality, you may need to make operational adjustments to your setup before you can proceed.
>
> By default, the Ubuntu installer can detect certain RAID configurations, but it may not necessarily be able to access and use the hard disks grouped in them.

https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Comment: @user535733 updated.