# Can we use WUBI or something like it to install Ubuntu in 2021 without bricking our Windows install?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

I would like to install Ubuntu using WUBI or something similar (from inside Windows). The general consensus seems to be that WUBI might be dangerous(?) but nobody seems to be sure. And you get the same results when you search for alternatives, with the only one mentioned by name being recommended against.

Assuming it can be done, does anyone know if this is hard on an SSD? How about repeated OS installs like we used to do with HDDs? Should I be doing as little of that as possible?

I'm a programmer with very little knowledge in the way of hardware, so please ELI5 (Explain Like I'm Five).

Thanks for your time, all.

Comment: Wubi has been discontinued eight years ago. See the official guide for how to install Ubuntu. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview Reinstalling operating systems a few times should not affect your SSD (unless you keep reinstalling everyday).

Comment: Start looking into virtualbox or vmware or WSL. Those are the 3. And I reinstall every 6 months. My notebook's battery still dies quicker than my ssd. Newer ssd are pretty good in that regard :P

Comment: @Draygoes: If your computer boots in UEFI mode, you can create a small FAT32 partition 3GB to 11GB and extract the Ubuntu ISO file to that. When you boot you will be offered the choice to boot Ubuntu. You can add a "writable" file up to 4GB and a "home-rw" file up to 4GB if you want persistence. If you don't use persistence the Live frugal install of Ubuntu never writes to SSD.

Answer (score 2):

### Boot Ubuntu on UEFI computer without USB or CD or GRUB

- Create FAT32 partition 3GB to 11GB, depending on the need for persistence.
- Copy/Paste contents of ISO file to new partition using 'Files' or 'Archive Manager'.*
- Reboot pressing F12 and select UEFI Ubuntu.You will be offered the choice to boot Ubuntu.
- You can add a "writable" file up to 4GB and a "home-rw" file up to 4GB if you want persistence, (the ability to save data between sessions).

**To create persistence file:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F casper-rw
```

- (Replace 512 with the "size in MB" you require, max 4000)
- For Ubuntu 20.04 and later replace `casper-rw` with `writable`
- For a `home-rw` file replace `casper-rw` with `home-rw`
- If you don't use persistence the Live frugal install of Ubuntu never writes to disk and can not wear the SSD out.

*If there is any problem opening the ISO file, Install 7Zip in Windows or P7zip in Linux.

**This method does not work on BIOS/Legacy only Computers**